# Sampling distribution of a functional T

Tags: statistical-inference, sampling, sampling-theory, bootstrap-sampling

While studying the bootstrap method, I came across with the following definition of the sampling distribution of a functional T:

---

Let's say $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d with distribution function $F$, then we estimate $T(F)$ by $T(F_n) \equiv  T_n$, where $F_n$ is the empirical d.f.

Consider the estimation of:

$H_n(x,F) \equiv P_F(\sqrt n(T_n - T(F)) \leq x).$

---

And then they explain how we can estimate that function.

My question is, why can we define the sampling distribution of a functional like that?

Thanks

Comment: This is about statistical distributions, not the [generalized function type of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), is it?

Comment: Yes, statistical distributions @md2perpe

Comment: Then I remove the tag 'distribution-theory'.